# Programmatically set all form fields to ng-touched on form submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" 
     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.firstName.$invalid && form.firstName.$touched }">
  <label for="firstName" 
         class="control-label">
         First Name
  </label>
  <input type="text" 
         name="firstName" 
         id="firstName" 
         ng-model="editableUser.firstName" 
         class="form-control" 
         required>
  <span class="help-block" 
        ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required && form.firstName.$touched">
        First Name is required
  </span>
</div>

<input type="submit" 
       ng-click="submit()" 
       value="Submit" 
       class="btn btn-default">
```

I'm trying to get my the 'has-error' class to kick in for invalid fields when a user clicks submit.

I would think you could do something like this:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  if ($scope.form.$invalid) {
    angular.forEach($scope.form.$invalid, function(field) {
      field.$setTouched();
    });
    alert("Form is invalid.");
  }
};
```

But there is no `$setTouched` method in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

**EDIT:** Realize `$setTouched` does exist, it's in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: What does one of your form fields look like? Could you edit your question to include an example? I'm interested why you are checking for $touched as well?

Comment: what if you use setDirty instead?

Comment: @BenHeymink Added code to clarify.

Comment: form.control.markAllAsTouched()

Comment: Again @Pankwood, wrong. This is AngularJS, NOT Angular!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
if ($scope.form.$invalid) {
    angular.forEach($scope.form.$error, function (field) {
        angular.forEach(field, function(errorField){
            errorField.$setTouched();
        })
    });
    alert("Form is invalid.");
}
```

plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XmvoTkIQ0yvFukrVSz11

Answer (score 16):

Try the recently added $submitted

```
<input type="text" 
     name="firstName" 
     id="firstName" 
     ng-model="editableUser.firstName" 
     class="form-control" 
     required>
   <span class="help-block" 
    ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required && (form.firstName.$touched || form.$submitted">
    First Name is required
```

Comment: In addition - if your function is triggered by an anchor element rather than an input of type submit - you might want to add      `$scope.myForm.$setSubmitted();` to  your function.

Comment: I like this solution the best - no need for extra controller logic if you can just use the built-in logic instead!

Comment: Thanks for a great tip about $submitted property! In my case works fine the following - "fullname.invalid && (fullname.touched || form.submitted)"

Answer (score 7):

Extending on Alexey's answer, you can add new method to FormController that will do the same, so there's no need to copy code from one submit function to another:

```
// config.js
export default function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('formDirective', $delegate => {
        const fn = $delegate[0].controller.prototype
        if (!('$setTouched' in fn)) fn.$setTouched = function() {
            if (this.$invalid) {
                Object.values(this.$error).forEach(controls => {
                    controls.forEach(control => control.$setTouched())
                })
            }
        }
        return $delegate
    })
}
```

```
// controller.js
$scope.submit = function () {
    if ($scope.form.$invalid) {
        $scope.form.$setTouched();
        alert("Form is invalid.");
    }
};
```

In case someone wonders why would anyone want to do this kind of validation: iOS constraint validation is lacking, so `ng-submit` gets called even on invalid forms.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers did not work for me.. to programatically set Touched true.

example, even after executing this `$scope.frmUser["U_Name"].$setTouched();`
`$scope.frmUser["U_Name"].$invalid` always stayed true.

And submit button was to be enabled only if `$scope.frmUser.$invalid` is false

Instead taking scope variable for each of fields to be set from programatically from javascript and setting it true / false worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy uisng ES6 + lodash fp

```
import forEach from 'lodash/fp/forEach'

    validate()
    {
        forEach(forEach(field => field.$setTouched()))(this.form.$error)
    }

<form name="$ctrl.form">...</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

These are all poor answers for the current v12 version of Angular.  It can be done simply with

```
submit() {
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();
}
```

Comment: Your comment is the poorest, cause we are talkiong about AngularJS here mate. NOT Angular.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure why you think you have to 'touch' the fields, just use regular form validation; you simply need to wrap your fields in an actual form element, then let angular take care of the validation for you. [Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5zc576az/12/).

You really don't need to check for $touched, or even set it (unless there is a specific reason why you need to do this?) - just use the required attribute on the input fields if they are required fields:

```
<input name="namefield" "text" ng-model="user.firstName" required/>
```

Comment: Because sometimes you only want error styles to apply and messages to appear after the user tried to submit the form for the first time. I think this is what most people are used to. jQuery Validate behaves like that as well. I didn't vote you down btw.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems a bit of an anti-pattern to allow the user to perform an action you know will fail (Allowing them to hit submit when you have client-side validation), but each to their own :)

Comment: For instance a form with input type email would distract you with error messages until the address you enter is well-formed. The user should have the chance to complete the form without an error if his input is valid in the end.